# Java : Trying to find out a string in a line after a particular string and few characters

Tags: java

I have a log file which has lines like below.

> GET /common/data/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 254614 "https://www.test.com/hiii/ "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.8) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/

I am trying to get the http status code which is 200 in the above line.
This will be placed after the string `HTTP/1.1"`.
Version of http (here it is 1.1) may not be common in all the lines.

Please help me out in finding out the http status code in each line.

Comment: a common way of solving this type of problem is using a regex, you could google that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: -

```
    String str = "GET /common/data/register/ HTTP/1.1\" 200 254614 " +
            "https://www.test.com/hiii/ Mozilla/5.0 " +
            "(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.8) " +
            "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/ ";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("HTTP/\\d.\\d\"\\s(\\d{3})");
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (match.find()) {
        System.out.println(match.group(1));  // Prints 200
    }
```

Here's an explanation of the above Regex: -

- **`HTTP/\\d.\\d\"`** -> Will match `HTTP/1.1"`. You can have any status (e.g: 5.4)
- **`\\d.\\d`** -> To match two digits separated by a dot.
- **`(\\d{3})`** -> To match 3 digits in continuity to match status code. We have captured it in a group, since we want this information.

Comment: Thanks so much for the timely help Rohit.. Its an awesome stuff. Please let me know where i can learn about Regex.

Comment: You're welcome :) And see this link for a start: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `inputString.split(" ")` which will return Array of string, 3rd element should be the status code.

Comment: Thank you.. But the line was just a look alike. There may be few more parameters such as IP at the beginning. Regex did the trick. will try this for another requirement. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Does the line always contain http/1.1 ?
If so you shoul be able to use the substring method in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Comment: not that in this case you also need to find the position of the " sign after 1.1

Comment: yeah.. Better to use Regex in this case. thanks for the API.